# adding a border-radius without padding to fancybox2

Tags: fancybox, rounded-corners, css

I'm using fancybox 2 and I can get rid of the padding around the outside of the frame, but then I lose the border-radius that it comes with.
What I want is a border-radius around the main content inside the frame. So I tried going into the css and adding a border-radius to the fancy-box inner selector and it won't work. How can I give the frame a rounded corner without a border? 
If anyone can help me with this that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it worked for me

Add custom classes after fancy box on complete method.

Ex.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#signin-container" class="signin-ovr"> Login </a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".signin-ovr").fancybox({
        afterLoad   :   function(){
                            $("#fancybox-content").addClass('fancybox-content-cust');
                            $(".fancybox-bg").addClass('fancybox-bg-cust');
                            $("#fancybox-outer").addClass('fancybox-outer-cust');
                        }

    });     
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fancybox-content-cust {
    overflow: visible !important;
    border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.fancybox-bg-cust{
    display: none;  
}

.fancybox-outer-cust {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

Then you will get border radius to the overlay box.

Comment: Note that Fancybox version 2 does not support onComplete. It uses afterLoad.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816130/fancybox-oncomplete-function-not-running

Comment: **However** I found only adding classes in the `afterShow` method to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

for fancybox v2 round borders

```
.fancybox-outer, .fancybox-inner, .fancybox-skin {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 10px!important;
}
```

Comment: Care to explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 has a border radius property ironically enough entitled `border-radius` there are a few specific variations ie, Firefoxes `moz-border-radius`.

It is used like so:

```
#div-id .specific-class {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

If you only want one rounded it has the ability to be modified like so

```
border-top-left-radius:2em;
border-top-right-radius:2em;
border-bottom-right-radius:2em;
border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks but i know that... i want the fancy box frame to know that too.

Comment: you know what... never mind. i can add a border-radius to the body of the iframe that is being shown in the light box and then it will be round....i think. and yes i was trying to add a border-radius to the fancy box.css