# Fancybox onComplete function not running

Tags: jquery, fancybox

For some reason it's just not running the `onComplete` function.  It does however load the fancybox div.   My html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="orange">

           #1 <a href="#text">click here</a>

           <div id="text" class="text">text text text</div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

My jquery:

```
 jQuery('li a').fancybox({       
    'autoDimensions':   'false',
    'width' :   631,
    'height':   256,        
    'onComplete':function(){

        alert('running');
        jQuery('.fancybox-skin').css('background-color',colour);
    }
});
```

the alert doesn't run.  I've also tried changing the event function to `onClosed` and the other events, and nothing.

Comment: have you considered? http://jsfiddle.net/3Nf4c/

Comment: this is the solution for fancybox 2

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295746/fancybox-2-height-not-working

Answer (score 18):

I guess you forgot to specify what version of fancybox you are using.

`onComplete` is a callback option for fancybox v1.3.x while the `fancybox-skin` *class* was introduced until version 2.x, ..... so I assume that you are using version 2.x, aren't you?

Fancybox v2.x options are new and not compatible with previous versions; the equivalent for the `onComplete` (v1.3.x) option is now the `afterLoad` (v2.x) callback option.

Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs for the complete list of options, methods and callbacks for fancybox v2.x

Comment: thanks for that.  I was looking here - http://fancybox.net/  is that a different fancybox then?

Comment: It's basically the same plugin (and the same author) but version 1.x and 2.x have different web pages because their different features and license plans. Please don't forget to mark this answer as correct if you consider it so. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, `afterShow` would make way more sense to use if you plan on adding any events. `afterLoad` fires as soon as it's ready to load _before_ it shows anything at all

Comment: @JunaidBhura : we are looking at a question/answer that is almost one year old and at that time `afterLoad` was the right callback to use. Today, if you ask me again, I would use `beforeShow` with the latest version of fancybox (v2.1.4) ..... unfortunately it's very difficult to keep updated most answers in SO and people should beware that some answers may be outdated.

Answer (score 7):

`afterShow` I think is the proper equivalent to `onComplete` in Fabxybox 2

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. I was adding an image map to one slide out of a set.  `afterShow` did the job as intended.  `afterLoad` was not the correct event for adding this attribute: `$('.fancybox-image').attr('usemap', '#Map');`

Answer (score 2):

Fancybox version 2 does not support `onComplete`. It uses `afterLoad`.

```
jQuery('#tips li a').fancybox({       
    'autoDimensions':   'false',
    'width' :   631,
    'height':   256,        
    afterLoad:function(){

        alert('running');
        jQuery('.fancybox-skin').css('background-color',colour); // colour to 'red' for example. typo
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like Typo

```
jQuery('#tips li a').fancybox({       
'autoDimensions':   'false',
'width' :   631,
'height':   256,        
'onComplete':function(){

    alert('running');
    jQuery('.fancybox-skin').css('background-color',colour); // colour to 'red' for example. typo
}
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/JWyd5/)

Comment: that doesn't work, yes it loads the alert, but the bg colour doesn't change

Comment: onComplete function is working right? You say it loads the alert. but you want to change  `.fancybox-skin` background color? could you provide the site link

Comment: i didnt find `.fancybox-skin` selector in jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css

Answer (score 0):

Use *afterLoad* instead of *onComplete*